# How to feed an Opencv frame into Nvidia Deepstream pipeline?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am struggling to find a away to input a single cv::Mat frame into a Nvidia Deepstream Pipeline using c++. I tried the code below but I received the following Error message:

ERROR from element gstappsrc: Internal data stream error.

Error details: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:dst_opencv/GstAppSrc:source:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Returned, stopping playback

Deleting pipeline

If anyone have an idea how to do it or show me where I am doing wrong, I will be very thankful.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "gstnvdsmeta.h"
#include "nvdsmeta_schema.h"
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>

/* The muxer output resolution must be set if the input streams will be of
 * different resolution. The muxer will scale all the input frames to this
 * resolution. */
#define MUXER_OUTPUT_WIDTH 1920
#define MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIGHT 1080

#define TILED_OUTPUT_WIDTH 1920
#define TILED_OUTPUT_HEIGHT 1080

/* Muxer batch formation timeout, for e.g. 40 millisec. Should ideally be set
 * based on the fastest source's framerate. */
#define MUXER_BATCH_TIMEOUT_USEC 4000000

/* NVIDIA Decoder source pad memory feature. This feature signifies that source
 * pads having this capability will push GstBuffers containing cuda buffers. */
#define GST_CAPS_FEATURES_NVMM "memory:NVMM"

// detection models
#define MODEL_CONFIG "dstest3_pgie_config.txt"
//#define MODEL_CONFIG "yoloV2_pgie_config.txt"
//#define MODEL_CONFIG "fd_lpd_config.txt"

#define FPS_PRINT_INTERVAL 300

static gboolean bus_call (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * msg, gpointer data)
{
  GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("End of stream\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_WARNING:
    {
      gchar *debug;
      GError *error;
      gst_message_parse_warning (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_printerr ("WARNING from element %s: %s\n",
          GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), error->message);
      g_free (debug);
      g_printerr ("Warning: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      break;
    }
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
    {
      gchar *debug;
      GError *error;
      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_printerr ("ERROR from element %s: %s\n",
          GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), error->message);
      if (debug)
        g_printerr ("Error details: %s\n", debug);
      g_free (debug);
      g_error_free (error);
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
static void cb_newpad (GstElement * decodebin, GstPad * decoder_src_pad, gpointer data)
{
  g_print ("In cb_newpad\n");
  GstCaps *caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (decoder_src_pad);
  const GstStructure *str = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);
  const gchar *name = gst_structure_get_name (str);
  GstElement *source_bin = (GstElement *) data;
  GstCapsFeatures *features = gst_caps_get_features (caps, 0);

  /* Need to check if the pad created by the decodebin is for video and not
   * audio. */
  if (!strncmp (name, "video", 5)) {
    /* Link the decodebin pad only if decodebin has picked nvidia
     * decoder plugin nvdec_*. We do this by checking if the pad caps contain
     * NVMM memory features. */
    if (gst_caps_features_contains (features, GST_CAPS_FEATURES_NVMM)) {
      /* Get the source bin ghost pad */
      GstPad *bin_ghost_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (source_bin, "src");
      if (!gst_ghost_pad_set_target (GST_GHOST_PAD (bin_ghost_pad),
              decoder_src_pad)) {
        g_printerr ("Failed to link decoder src pad to source bin ghost pad\n");
      }
      gst_object_unref (bin_ghost_pad);
    } else {
      g_printerr ("Error: Decodebin did not pick nvidia decoder plugin.\n");
    }
  }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
static void decodebin_child_added (GstChildProxy * child_proxy, GObject * object,gchar * name, gpointer user_data)
{
  g_print ("Decodebin child added: %s\n", name);
  if (g_strrstr (name, "decodebin") == name) {
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (object), "child-added",
        G_CALLBACK (decodebin_child_added), user_data);
  }
  if (g_strstr_len (name, -1, "nvv4l2decoder") == name) {
    g_print ("Seting bufapi_version\n");
    g_object_set (object, "bufapi-version", TRUE, NULL);
  }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
void buffer_destroy(gpointer data) {cv::Mat* done = (cv::Mat*)data; delete done;}
//-----------------------------------------------------
static gboolean cb_need_data(GstElement* appsrc,guint unused_size,gpointer user_data)
{
  g_print("cb_need_data function \n");
  GstBuffer* buffer; 
  GstMapInfo map;
  guint size,depth,height,width,step,channels;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  guchar *data1;

  g_print("userdata: %s \n",user_data);

  
  cv::Mat frame=cv::imread((const char*)user_data, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

  height    = frame.size().height;  
  width     = frame.size().width;
  channels  = frame.channels();
  data1      = (guchar *)frame.data;
  gsize sizeInBytes = height*width*channels;
 

  g_print("frame_height: %d \n",height);
  g_print("frame_width: %d \n",width);
  g_print("frame_channels: %d \n",channels);
  g_print("frame_size: %d \n",sizeInBytes);
  
  buffer=gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,sizeInBytes,NULL);
  gst_buffer_map(buffer,&map,GST_MAP_WRITE);
  memcpy( (guchar *)map.data, data1,  gst_buffer_get_size( buffer ) );

  g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
  
  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {g_print("cv 2 gst got an error"); return false;}
  gst_buffer_unref(buffer);
  //gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map); 
  g_print("cv converted to gst \n ");
  return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
static GstPadProbeReturn tiler_src_pad_buffer_probe (GstPad * pad, GstPadProbeInfo * info,gpointer u_data)
{
    char *msg;
    g_object_get(G_OBJECT(u_data),"last-message",&msg,NULL);
    if (msg!=NULL) {g_print("FPS =%s \n",msg);}
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
//------------------MAIN---------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------
    int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstElement *pipeline,*sink,*tiler,*nvvidconv,*nvosd,*nvsink,*pgie; //,*streammux
    GstElement* appsrc,*conv;
    GstBus *bus;
    guint bus_watch_id;
    GstPad *tiler_src_pad;
    guint num_sources;
    guint tiler_rows,tiler_columns;
    guint pgie_batch_size;
    GstCaps *caps;

    //check input args
    if(argc <2) {g_printerr("Usage: %s <uri1> [uri2] ... [uriN] \n", argv[0]); return -1;}
    num_sources=argc-1;
    
    //start gstreamer
    gst_init(&argc,&argv);
    loop=g_main_loop_new(NULL,FALSE);

    //Creating pipeline
    pipeline=gst_pipeline_new("dst_opencv");
    //streammux=gst_element_factory_make("nvstreammux","nvstream-muxer");

    if(!pipeline){g_printerr("pipeline could not be created");}
    //if(!streammux){g_printerr("Streammux could not be created");}
    //gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline),streammux);

    // Creating bin with all sources

    appsrc=gst_element_factory_make("appsrc","gstappsrc");
    conv=gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert","conv");

    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",
        gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
                     "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "I420",
                     "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1200,
                     "height", G_TYPE_INT, 600,
                     "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1, 1,
                     NULL), NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc),"stream-type",0,"format",GST_FORMAT_TIME,NULL);
 
     /* Use nvinfer to infer on batched frame. */
    pgie = gst_element_factory_make ("nvinfer", "primary-nvinference-engine");
    
    /* Use nvtiler to composite the batched frames into a 2D tiled array based
   * on the source of the frames. */
    tiler = gst_element_factory_make ("nvmultistreamtiler", "nvtiler");

    nvvidconv=gst_element_factory_make ("nvvideoconvert","nvvideo-converter");

    /* Use convertor to convert from NV12 to RGBA as required by nvosd */
   // nvvidconv = gst_element_factory_make ("nvvideoconvert", "nvvideo-converter");
    nvosd=gst_element_factory_make("nvdsosd","nv-onscreendisplay");

    nvsink=gst_element_factory_make ("nveglglessink", "nvvideo-renderer"); //show on display
    //nvsink=gst_element_factory_make("fakesink","nvvideo-render"); //Dont show frames on screen
    sink=gst_element_factory_make("fpsdisplaysink","fps_display");
    //sink=gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink","videosink");

    //check if all plugin were created
    if(!appsrc){g_printerr("appsrc could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!conv){g_printerr("conv could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!tiler){g_printerr("tiler could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!sink){g_printerr("sink could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!nvvidconv){g_printerr("nvvidconv could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!pgie){g_printerr("pgie could not be created"); return -1;}
    if(!nvosd){g_printerr("nvosd could not be created"); return -1;}

    //set streammux
     

      /* Configure the nvinfer element using the nvinfer config file. */
     g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pgie),"config-file-path", MODEL_CONFIG, NULL);

    /* Override the batch-size set in the config file with the number of sources. */
    g_object_get (G_OBJECT (pgie), "batch-size", &pgie_batch_size, NULL);
    if (pgie_batch_size != num_sources) {
        g_printerr("WARNING: Overriding infer-config batch-size (%d) with number of sources (%d)\n",pgie_batch_size, num_sources);
        g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pgie), "batch-size", num_sources, NULL);}

    //g_print("Flag \n"); 

    //set tiler 
    tiler_rows = (guint) sqrt (num_sources);
    tiler_columns = (guint) ceil (1.0 * num_sources / tiler_rows);
    /* we set the tiler properties here */
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (tiler), "rows", tiler_rows, "columns", tiler_columns,
      "width", TILED_OUTPUT_WIDTH, "height", TILED_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, NULL);

    /* we add a message handler */
    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
    bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

   //set fps sink
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "text-overlay", FALSE, "video-sink", nvsink, "sync", FALSE, NULL);
    
    //linking all elements
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),appsrc,conv,pgie,tiler,nvvidconv,nvosd,sink,NULL);
    if (!gst_element_link_many(appsrc,conv,pgie,tiler,nvvidconv,nvosd,sink,NULL)){g_printerr("Elements could not be linked"); return -1;}
      
    tiler_src_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (pgie, "src");
    if (!tiler_src_pad) {g_print ("Unable to get src pad\n");}
    else{gst_pad_add_probe (tiler_src_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,tiler_src_pad_buffer_probe, (gpointer)sink, NULL);}
  
    g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (cb_need_data),(gpointer)argv[1]);

    /* Set the pipeline to "playing" state */
    g_print ("Now playing:");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_sources; i++) {g_print (" %s,", argv[i + 1]);}
    g_print ("\n");
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    /* Wait till pipeline encounters an error or EOS */
    g_print ("Running...\n");
    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    /* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
    g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n");
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
    g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
    g_main_loop_unref (loop);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may be dumplicate with
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114460/push-opencv-mat-inside-a-deepstream-pipeline